# no response in discord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hey so when I type $opgg or $ftgopgg it will not come up with anything on the following

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content('$opgg'): 
    response = 'Spend me the names'
    await message.channel.send(response)
    def check(m):
      return m.author.id == message.author.id


    
    opgg = await bot.wait_for('message')
    await message.channel.send(f'https://oce.op.gg/multi/query={opgg.content.replace(" ", "%20")}')
    print("done")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content == '$ftgopgg': 
    teamopgg = "https://oce.op.gg/multi/query=Disco Inferno, spranze, killogee, blank76, reeks"
    
    
    await message.send(teamopgg.replace(" ", "%20"))
    
    print("Tdone")
```

it was working like an hour ago but I could not use both commands, I don't know if I've gotten code work or if there is a mistake

Comment: You can't have 2 functions with the same name, this is also the case with `discord.py` --  you can't have 2 `on_message`(s), combine them both in one.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 `on_message` events but **discord.py** supports only one.

If you are trying to create commands for your bot I recommend use `@client.command()` decorator instead of listening `on_message` event.

Something like:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$", intents=discord.Intents.all())

@bot.command()
async def opgg(ctx):
    response = "Spend me the names"
    await message.channel.send(response)
    def check(m):
      return m.author.id == message.author.id

@bot.command()
async def ftgopgg(ctx):
    teamopgg = "https://oce.op.gg/multi/query=Disco Inferno, spranze, killogee, blank76, reeks"
    await message.send(teamopgg.replace(" ", "%20"))
    print("Tdone")

bot.run("TOKEN")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use **bot.command()** and **on_message** event at the same time, you can use :

```
@bot.listen()
async def on_message(message):
```

instead of:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix all i had to do was remove the lower `@bot.event` and `async def on_message(message)`

new code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content('$opgg'): 
    response = 'Spend me the names'
    await message.channel.send(response)
    def check(m):
      return m.author.id == message.author.id


    
    opgg = await bot.wait_for('message')
    await message.channel.send(f'https://oce.op.gg/multi/query={opgg.content.replace(" ", "%20")}')
    print("done")

 if message.content == '$ftgopgg': 
    teamopgg = "https://oce.op.gg/multi/query=Disco Inferno, spranze, killogee, blank76, reeks"
    
    
    await message.send(teamopgg.replace(" ", "%20"))
    
    print("Tdone")
```